# Angular 2: using property as HTML tag name

Tags: html, angular

It's possible to use property as HTML tag name?
Something like this or similar:

```
<{{property.name}}>Hello world</{{property.name}}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported. Tags and attributes used as component or directive selector need to be added statically.

If you want to add components dynamically you can use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` like demonstrated in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Answer (score 0):

no you can use like this

```
<label>{{property.name}}</label>
```

or

```
<htmltag>{{property.name}}</htmltag>
```